# Maximum weighted matching in Bipartite Graph

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching

I was solving a coding question which boiled down to this problem.
Given a bipartite graph $G=\{V\cup U,E\}$. There is a positive value given for every node in  $U$.
Now we have to find the matching in which the sum of value of every node in $U$ which is also in the matching is maximum.
Consider an example, Let valueArray for $U = [1,2,3]$ . If in a matching nodes 0 and 1 of array are in matching the value of matching will be valueArray[0]+valueArray[1] = 3.
We have to find this maximum possible value of all possible matching given the graph and valueArray.
Matching nedd not be of maximum cardinality.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to maximize. Let $M$ be the maximum cardinality over all matchings of $G$ (recall that a matching is a set of edges). Are you looking to maximize (i) the sum of the values of the matched nodes in $U$ over all possible matchings of $G$, or (ii) the sum of the values of the matched nodes in $U$ over all possible matchings of $G$ of cardinality $M$?

Comment: It is i) There is no cardinality constraint on the matching

Comment: Then you just want a maximum weight bipartite matching. Use the transformation in Pål GD's answer to get the edge-weighted variant. Then add dummy edges of weight $0$ to ensure that a perfect matching always exists.  Finally, use any algorithm for minimum/maximum weight bipartite matching. See again Pål GD's answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I was thinking whether the question has a simpler solution as it was one of the three question asked in exam having 60 mins time to complete the code for all the three.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the problem into an edge-weighted variant by setting the weight on edge $vu$ to be $\texttt{valueArray}(u)$ where $w(vu) = \texttt{valueArray}(u)$ is the value of $u \in U$.

Now a maximum weight matching in this graph is a matching which maximizes the sum of the values of the nodes in $U$.  Note that you can flip the sign of all values to obtain a minimization problem, and if you add all missing edges with $w(e) = 0$.  Now you have a *minimum-weight perfect matching* problem.

Ps, this is called the [*assignment problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and can be solved using LP, by the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (augmenting paths), or the [*min-cost* max flow algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).